Having trouble with a SQL query
I am asked this question:

How many customers transact in a city other than their home city? You will need to find each customer’s Home Branch location and compare it to the location of their transaction (i.e. Transaction City).

I have 3 tables, one for branchdata with two columns, branchnumber and location
Customerdata with customerid, name, age, city,homebranch, accountbalance
transactiondata with transactionid, transactionamount, transactioncity, customerid, accountnumber.
I am having trouble joining the customerdata and transactiondata tables in order to look at the customerid, transactioncity and homebranch.
Any help on where to start would be much appreciated.
I have tried these two queries
select customerid, city, homebranch
from customerdata 

select Transactioncity, customerid
from transactiondata

I can get the answer by looking at these two separately however I am assuming it should all be done in one query.

"I am having trouble joining the customerdata and transactiondata tables". What kind of trouble are you having? It looks like you haven't even tried. Please show your attempt and we'll help you fix it. We don't do your homework for you.

The solution involves from customer data join transactiondata and the joining criteria uses customerid and compares customerdata.city with transactiondata.transactioncity.

You're also confusing databases with tables. You have 1 database containing 3 tables.

So as Luty above showed to solve this problem u need to JOIN tables
SO let's call
customer - c
transaction - t
branch - b (but as i understand branch will be unnecesary for this task)
At this point we can make select
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM customerdata AS c
JOIN transactiondata AS t ON c.customerid = t.customerid
WHERE c.city != t.transactioncity

Let's break down query
We SELECT COUNT(*) select count of rows that will be correct with our WHERE c.city != t.transaction so we check if c - customer city is diffrent then t - transaction city and if they are != not same they will be counted
FROM customerdata means we mainly access data of customerdata table but since we want more then 1 table with similar field to recognize them we need name each with an alias like shorting theyr names to 1 letter like "c"
we do that with AS c
Compare to your query i added JOIN transactiondata AS t ON c.customerid = t.customerid this means that we gona ADDS all fields from table transactiondatato our customerdata but as before we need to name it to recognize witch table we access to we adds AS t after this we need to clarify which data from transactiondata matches customerdata so we add statementc.customerid = t.customerid``
But at this point we only COUNT(*) all transactions that have been made in other city then customers home
So to count each customer only once we have to make it unique by call DISTINCT to the field that we want to be unique
So we end up with query like
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.customerid)
FROM customerdata AS c
JOIN transactiondata AS t ON c.customerid = t.customerid
WHERE c.city != t.transactioncity



First, you need to join the tables by their keys. To do that you will use JOIN command:

  FROM customerdata c
    JOIN transactiondata t ON c.customerid = t.customerid
    JOIN branchdata b ON c.homebranch = b.branchnumber


To filter the transactions in order the remove those from the home branch you can use the WHERE clasule:

  WHERE t.transactioncity <> b.location


Finally, you can select the number of unique customers and count them using the built-in sql function COUNT. The DISTINCT directive will make sure the result will discard the duplicated customers.

  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.customerid) AS num_customers

Wrapping everything above up:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.customerid) AS num_customers
FROM customerdata c
JOIN transactiondata t ON c.customerid = t.customerid
JOIN branchdata b ON c.homebranch = b.branchnumber
WHERE t.transactioncity <> b.location;


If you're going to do someone's homework for them, you should at least explain how it works so that they learn something in the process.

@KenWhite You are rigtht. I've edited the question to add the explanation

Thank you so much for the help and explaining it, I was having so much trouble figuring out why it wouldn’t let me join the tables
